# Angular Erro ao mudar de estado, comunicação entre components via serviço

Tags: angular

podem me ajudar:

Error: ExpressionChangedAfterHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'attr.aria-describedby': 'msg-default'. Current value? 'id-0'

Estou usando um serviço para pegar o id do componente "app-msg-erro" e passar para o atributo do input do component "app-radio-button", esta passando OK, mas no console estou recebendo o erro a cima.

Segue cód:
erro.service

```
``
    export class MsgErrorService {
    
    private _msgError = new BehaviorSubject<string>('msg-defaut');
    
    currentMsg = this._msgError.asObservable();
    
    constructor() {}
    
    changeError(msg: string) {
      this._msgError.next(msg);
    }

``
```

Cód do component

```
`` 
        export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {
        
        constructor(private msgErrorService: MsgErrorService) {}
        
        @Input()
        @HostBinding(attr.id)
        errorMsgId: `msg-erro-${id++}`
        }
    
    ngOnInit(){
     this.msgErrorService.changeError(this.errorMSgId);
    }
    
    ``
```

Answer (score 0):

pesquisando encontrei duas soluções.

uma seria passar a linha abaixo dentro do constructor opção 1

```
 constructor(private msgErrorService: MsgErrorService) {
    this.msgErrorService.changeError(this.errorMSgId);
 }
```

E/ou usar um if e verificar a variavel que recebe o ID, opção 2

```
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {
        
        constructor(private msgErrorService: MsgErrorService) {}
        
        @Input()
        @HostBinding(attr.id)
        errorMsgId: `msg-erro-${id++}`
        }
    
    ngOnInit(){
     if(this.errorMsgId) {
        this.msgErrorService.changeError(this.errorMSgId);
     }
     
    }
   }
```